# I want to convert all values inside Elementree to their corresponding string values

Tags: python, elementtree

I tried this

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
root = Element('root')
child = SubElement(root, "child")
child.text = 123
print tostring(root)
```

which throws following error

```
TypeError: cannot serialize 123 (type int)
```

I know that **str() function** can be used here
however it is not possible in my case

Is there any other library functions that i can use ??

Comment: maybe go into a bit of detail about why you can't use the str() function. Maybe you have a different issue....

Answer (score 0):

use the str() function to convert int to string
 child.text = str(123)

Comment: I've already mentioned i can't use str() function in my case. I am looking for a library to convert all values inside Elementree to corresponding string values

Comment: why don't you just do child.text = '123' to begin with? When parsing an xml with ElementTree, you convert the xml to a string format; hence you can't use int values. The ElementTree library assumes you are working with string values....

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you, as you say, don't want to use the str function, you could also do it with string formatting:

```
child.text = "%d" % 123
```

More exotic, you could use the JSON library:

```
import json

child.text = json.dumps(123)
```

But, let me emphasize, **`str(123)` is the best choice here** because it is going to be easiest for humans to understand.  You mention that this is not an option.  Is that because you assigned a variable to str?  That might not be a good idea in the long run.

Comment: I want to convert all values inside Elementree to their corresponding string values. To be tedious to use str() in my case